# Google Admin SDK Report API - Renaming a file from uppercase to lowercase error

Tags: google-api, google-admin-sdk

Playing with the Google Admin SDK I found out that When one of the users under a Google Apps Unlimited account renames a file to lowercase (i.e. from "Test file" to "test file") I see in the Audit logs an 'Edit' event instead of a 'Rename' event.

Is that intentional or is it a bug?

https://i.stack.imgur.com/hYtQ4.png

I am using the API Explorer from Google to test it developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/reference/activities/ and after renaming a file to lowercase this is the entry that the API Explorer returns http://prnt.sc/aacsic

Answer (score 0):

As [described in the docs](https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/reference/activity-ref-appendix-a/drive-event-names#access-events), a single user action can produce multiple events in the log. Check for other events and look for `primary_event=true` to better understand what the user might have actually done.

Comment: There is only one event in the `events` array, its primary_event=true, and the name of the event is 'name': 'edit', 'type': 'access'. There is not any event that says 'rename' @JayLee

Comment: I am using the API Explorer from Google to test it https://developers.google.com/admin-sdk/reports/v1/reference/activities/list

And after renaming a file to lowercase, this is the entry that the API Explorer returns http://prnt.sc/aacsic